# Is possible to find a single file of NOT installed package on Netbsd?

Tags: package-management, netbsd, pkgsrc

Simple question:

On Fedora, i want to search mplayer..

```
dnf provides *bin/mplayer
```

on Debian

```
apt -y install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search mplayer|grep bin
```

on Freebsd

```
pkg install -y pkg-provides
pkg provides -u 
pkg provides *bin/mplayer$
```

Anything similar on netbsd?
Actually seems no similar tool exist.